# R: if values of two columns of two data frames are equal, add column of one of the two data frames

Tags: r, merge, data-cleaning

I have two data frames

`columns df1= a, b, c, d`

`columns df2= e, f, c, d`

I want to say that if  `df1$a == df2$e` and at the same time `df1$b == df2$f` I want to print in a new column `df1$x` the values of the corresponding `df2$c`.

So I wrote this command `df1$x <- ifelse(df1$a %in% df2$e & df1$b %in% df2$f, df2$c, ifelse (NULL))`

But the values in `df1x` are not correct. I think I have to do a while loop, but I have no idea from where to start.

Nicoletta

Comment: Can you provide example input data and expected output? See [how to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: You can't put NULL as an element in a vector. You'll have to make it `NA`. That said, the code you provided has several typos (e.g., df$1 instead of df1$a), and there's no reason to use `%in%` - just use `==`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To merge two data frames by multiple columns you can use `merge` and corresponding `by.x` and `by.y`. Both of those accept vector of column names. Parameter `all.x` means all data from first `df1` will be preserved.

```
df1 <-  merge(df1, df2[,c("e","f","c")], by.x=c("a","b"), by.y=c("e","f"), all.x=T)

colnames(df1) <- c("a","b","c","d","x")
```

For more information see `?merge`. For more complex operation you can check out package `dplyr` and its function `left_join`.

**Result on random data**

```
df1 <- data.frame(a = sample(1:5), b= sample(1:5), c=runif(5), d = runif(5))
df2 <- data.frame(e = df1$a, f = df1$b, c = runif(5), d = runif(5))
df2$e[3] <- 7
```

Output

```
> df1
  a b          c          d
1 5 4 0.76677063 0.92123552
2 4 1 0.93524320 0.09275425
3 3 2 0.01121468 0.12035981
4 1 5 0.72992427 0.87711572
5 2 3 0.11680937 0.93696597
> df2$e[3] <- 7
> df2
  e f         c         d
1 5 4 0.6251662 0.1549575
2 4 1 0.8464672 0.8702837
3 7 2 0.5394273 0.4290171
4 1 5 0.4061817 0.9072905
5 2 3 0.3376456 0.4291463
> merge(df1, df2[,c("e","f","c")], by.x=c("a","b"), by.y=c("e","f"), all.x=T)
  a b          c          d         x
1 1 5 0.72992427 0.87711572 0.4061817
2 2 3 0.11680937 0.93696597 0.3376456
3 3 2 0.01121468 0.12035981        NA
4 4 1 0.93524320 0.09275425 0.8464672
5 5 4 0.76677063 0.92123552 0.6251662
```